# One input triggers Chrome validation, but another isn't

Tags: javascript, validation, google-chrome

I have three inputs across two pages, all of which I want Chrome to validate (i.e. they won't allow the form to be submitted if it doesn't contain a valid email address).

The input on [this page](http://www.comfyshoulderrest.com/shopaholic/) (input A) is validating fine, so I'd like to do the same with the inputs on [this page](http://www.comfyshoulderrest.com/shopaholic/demo/): the one you see when you click  `Options -> Add/remove feeds` or `Options -> Edit account` (input B) and the one you see when you click 'Get notified' (input C).

This is the code for input A, which is validating properly:

```
<form role="form" class="form-inline" method="POST">
    <p>Get notified when Shopaholic launches</p>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Notify me</button>
</form>
```

This is the code for inputs B and C, which **aren't** validating:

```
<!-- Modal containing input B -->
<div class="modal fade" id="getNotifiedModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="getNotifiedLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="getNotifiedModal1Label">Sorry, this feature is unavailable in the demo version.</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="p">But why not get notified when the full version of Shopaholic launches?</p>
                <form role="form" class="form-inline" method="POST">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Notify me</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal containing input C -->
<div class="modal fade" id="getNotifiedModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="getNotifiedLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="getNotifiedModal2">Get notified when Shopaholic launches!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form" class="form-inline" method="POST">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Notify me</button>
                </form>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I have just realised that it is Chrome doing this, not Bootstrap.

Comment: Please answer your own question. Otherwise it will stay on the list/under the tab 'Unanswered'.